# How to enable up-arrow command history and command completion in sftp on Gentoo?

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, gentoo, openssh, sftp

When I try to use up-arrow command history via sftp to my CentOS 7 server it just prints ASCII characters to the output instead of recalling recent commands:

```
sftp> ^[[A
```

It's very time consuming and annoying to have to retype commands all the time.  Is there also a way to enable something similar to bash-completion?

Comment: What sftp / OS are you using on the client side?

Comment: I'm using sftp from `OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018` on Gentoo Linux.

Comment: Not too familiar with gentoo, but perhaps the sftp client was configured without libedit? See [SFTP Configuration](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SFTP#Configuration)

Comment: @steeldriver, you're right, I rebuilt OpenSSH with use flags for libedit and it works now.  If you add as answer I'll accept.  Thanks man.

Comment: TBH I know less than zero about Gentoo - please consider writing your own answer outlining the steps required

Comment: @steeldriver, cheers mate, I have done so below.

Comment: Good job - upvoted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @[steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) who pointed out [libedit](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SFTP#Configuration) is needed.  So it was simply a matter of adding the `libedit` USE flag for portage.  I added it *locally*  like so:

```
# /etc/portage/package.use
>=net-misc/openssh-7.7_p1-r9 libedit
```

And then rebuilt OpenSSH:

```
$ emerge -av net-misc/openssh
```

---

**Additionally**, this requires `bash-completion` to already be *installed* and *enabled* for `sftp`.

Install bash completion:

```
$ sudo emerge --ask app-shells/bash-completion
```

You can check bash-completion is enabled for sftp like this:

```
$ eselect bashcomp list | grep ftp
```

Which should return somthing like:

```
  [337] lftp *
  [338] lftpget *
  [451] ncftp *
  [633] sftp *
```

The trailing asterisk confirms bash-completion is enabled for sftp, (and in this case, several other ftp utils also).